# How to Verify Subscriptions - Google Subscription

Tags: java, android, android-studio, in-app-purchase

I am using google purchase library 4.0. When customers want to start a subscription, they press the Buy button and make a purchase. If he closes the app or loses internet connection right after the purchase is complete, his payment cannot be verified. (onPurchasesUpdated) How can we prevent this? When I go to the Google Subscriptions page, it says Open App, but running the application is not enough to verify the payment. After a while, the user is automatically refunded. How can we prevent this?
I shared the github project made by google below. I am working on this project.

Problem: https://prnt.sc/1f5dp0o My Source: https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/tree/main/TrivialDriveJava

Answer (score 1):

The solution for your user is to "restore" his subscription within your app. In another words, you should add a link in your Paywall which, when clicked, will retrieve the subscription from the Play Store and send it back to your server/validate it in your app.

Here is an example of a Paywall with this restore link:

[image]

Ideally, you should add a restore button in your "settings" or "profile" page of your app. It's important your user find a way to fix this kind of error easily.

Another thing you could do is save in a boolean the fact you're beginning a subscription (and remove it when it ends). If at the next opening of your app this boolean is still present, you could manually start a restore or show a popup asking your user if he wants to restore (with a button to start the restore in the popup).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, is there a source code I can use for this?

Comment: I'm a backend developer so I don't have the code. But from what I know you have an API to get the existing subscriptions, and you just have to acknowledge the one that is not.